# Do biological brains compute using quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-turing-machine, quantum-biology, biocomputing

Someone on research gate said the answer was no

> Our brain is a neural network with a very complex connectome. Any system is in a sense a computer adhering quantum mechanics, but what is known about human brain doesn’t tell us it uses quantum-mechanical effects such as entangled states and superposition states as en essential element of computation.

So the human brain is more like a classical computer Or is the brain not like a Turing machine?

Comment: Essentially, no-one really knows and it's likely that no-one will know for a *long* time, so as far as I can tell, there's no way to actually answer this question. Any answer you get anywhere (as far as I'm aware) is pure speculation. If someone finds an actual peer-reviewed article on this, it'd be good to know, though

Comment: I don’t understand how this question is opinion based. Either human brains are quantum computers or they are not. Where is the room for opinion? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we know - and I know, so correct me anyone if there's research to the contrary - the neuron interactions in the brain are well within the classical regime.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5681944/

Comment: Well to make a quantum computer we need to understand it. And our neurons are classical computers, and we’re simulating how to make a quantum computer in our heads which will take forever in fact exponential time. But we will build it eventually.

Comment: @Numbers: You need exponentialy increasing computational resources for simulation of a quantum algorithm run, not for the understanding and creating its mathematical model.  Although brain is electro-chemical computer in classical sense, there is something above we do not understand well nowadays - our consciousness. Therefore I would not mix computer sciences with neural science.

Answer (score 2):

There is evidence that quantum coherence and it's role in chemical reactivity is responsible for the magnetic field sensing in migratory birds, the so called avian compass, https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5946v1.

Similar quantum effects and chemistry could very well be occuring and playing a role in the brain, though as far as I know there isn't anything published in that direction. And even if there is a role for quantum coherent effects, it is likely a far cry from how we think about quantum computing.